# Can't link fat iOS static library

Tags: ios, xcode, boost, static-libraries

I recently downloaded a fat, iOS static library for the popular C library [boost](https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost). All my attempts in coaxing Xcode to link it have **failed**.

Things I have tried:

- Adding it to **Link Binary With Libraries**.
- Changing file type to **Mach-O Object Code** using File Inspector.
- Renaming the file to `libboost.a` and adding `-lboost` to **Other Linker Flags**.

I am using Xcode 6.3  with the latest command line tools.

Comment: What to the error message?

Comment: There's no error. My project builds just fine, however the library is not linked.

Answer (score 0):

How To Link to an Xcode Project?

In **Xcode Build Settings** for your project: `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`

```
ofxiOSBoost/libs/boost/lib/ios
```

(Set this to the directory where the static library is)

In **Target under Build Phases** for your project

Add to 'Link Binary With Libraries' the `boost.a` found in the `ofxiOSBoost/libs/boost/lib/ios directory.`

Renaming to libboost.a may be breaking it. The ofxiOSBoost renames this file as to not conflict with internal OSX libs in the linking process if in path / sys, so it links correctly with the iOS Binary.

If you are still having this problem, please open an issue here:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost/issues